# Facing some problem with after() method in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, delay, wait

I am trying to print a string after some delay in my sample program. The problem I am facing is, I am getting the first string immediately without delay and second string after the delay. What I am doing wrong? Please correct me.
Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("after method")
root.geometry("100x100")

def displayint():
    print("hello world")

def display():
    root.after(5000,displayint())
    root.after(10000,displayint())

button = tk.Button(root,text='press',command = display)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/7414759)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis following the call to `displayint` in the function `display`:

```
def display():
    root.after(5000,displayint)
    root.after(10000,displayint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove parentheses from `displayint()`:

```
root.after(5000, displayint)
root.after(10000, displayint)
```